# DD4T How to Get Page from a Component TCMID

Tags: content-delivery, core-service

in DD4T, can I get Page from a Component TCMID? compare to CoreService usingItemsFilter to get pages. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the Linking API. Component links get resolved to ONE page that contains that component (the page with highest priority, search for link resolving in docs.sdl.com).

I don't know if DD4T has its own API wrapper for this, linking is standard tridion CD API.

Comment: thanks Nuno, got right function to get links from a search function